# Publish font through npm for use in project

Tags: angular, fonts, npm, glyph

I've created a set of music glyphs (notes, dotted notes, and time signatures) for use in a web-application I'm currently developing using angular2, as I wasn't able to find a font with glyphs I felt were appropriate for the application. My hierarchy for the font is as follows

- fonts

  - notes.eot
  - notes.svg
  - notes.ttf
  - notes.woff
- package.json (from npm init)
- readme.txt
- selection.json (from npm init)
- style.css

I'm now not sure what steps I need to take from here to publish this into npm (I'm happy to share these glyph sets through npm), and I haven't been able to find an article or StackOverflow answer that helps me. I would appreciate a list of steps to publish and use these glyphsets in my project.

Comment: Publish this as anything else, font files don't change anything.

Comment: get rid of those `eot` and `svg` versions, and don't serve people the `ttf` version. I know, webfonts have a long history of multiple formats and confusion in browsers, but at the end of 2016, WOFF (and WOFF2) won, and every browser on desktop and mobile supports it. See [this stackoverflow post](/a/37091681/740553) for more details on that (e.g microsoft no longer supports `eot`, `svg` hasn't been a valid format in years, `ttf` is a *system* font, not a webfont, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `npm publish` command will publish the entire npm-managed directory, based on the version tag you have in your `package.json` so protip: do your versioning using the `npm version major`, `npm version minor`, and `npm version patch` commands, don't manually bump them. The `npm version` command updates your package.json *and* automatically creates a git version tag for your project that you can push up to github.

See something like https://medium.com/@jdaudier/how-to-create-and-publish-your-first-node-js-module-444e7585b738#.imf0mtv0q for a good "start to finish" on publishing your project to npm.